In which order apps in ~/.config/autostart/ are started?
Is there any specification for this or it's implementation-dependent?

The XDG autostart specification, as far as I can tell, does not define the order.
So, it's implementation-dependent.
If you need things to start in a specific order, chances are the simplistic autostart mechanism is the wrong choice for you – you should just write small systemd user service files, and put them in your ~/.config/systemd/user/servicename.service, before you systemctl enable --user servicename.service them.
In such service files, you can either declare them WantedBy=default.target in the [Install] section, so they get started when you log in automatically, or if they are services that are needed by another service, you declare them as Requires=yourotherservice.service in that service's service file.

Yeah, I understand it. But to write a script that starts needed programs with & sign and to place a .desktop shortcut to it in ~/.config/autostart/ is ok too, right?

no, usually not: when you need a service, you need to wait until at has successfully started, not start it and in the same microsecond go and start the service that depends on the first which is what would happen if you did first &; second. The second service would start instantly, before the first actually came up; even worse, it'd start even if the first fails to start. That's literally why I said "is the wrong choice for you".
